# PIL image.rotate(expand=True) creating huge files with unnecessary background

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

The following piece of code rotates the images by 30 degrees

```
for angle in angles:
    image_new = image.rotate(angle, expand=True)
    image_new.save(newImage_path)
```

The expand part works fine for some images, but expands some images unnecessarily (even increases file size to around 2MB from around 200kb).
For example, the below image was rotated and the black background was added. I can't seem to find enough methods to manipulate images in PIL.

Edit: I have to use expand as otherwise I will lose part of image.

[image]

Comment: Did you create all  source images later differently rotated the same way and how?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. All source images are camera clicked jpeg images. I intend to apply rotate to all of them. I only tried for 30 degree rotation now, will do other angles later.

Comment: So the `Image` instances where all created using `Image.open(filename)` and show no excessive border when looked at via an image browser?

Comment: Yes, that's correct